# React components not taking full width of screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React JS and Material UI. The hero image does not fill up the width of the screen. I have tried setting the width of the component and it's parents to 100% but nothing changes. I haven't found any fix that fits my particular issue on here. Maybe I'm missing something? I'm a bit new to this. I've included code that replicates the issue below.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router >
    <App/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomeBody from "./HomeBody";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <HomeBody />
        </Route>
      </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HomeBody.js

```
import React from "react";
import Hero from "./Hero";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#151515"
  }
});

function HomeBody() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Hero />
    </div>
  );
}
export default HomeBody;
```

Hero.js

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#151515"
  },
  hero: {
    width: "100%"
  }
});
function Hero() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <img
          src="https://picsum.photos/1217/645"
          alt="hero"
          className={classes.hero}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```

styles.css

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#root {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The div parent in the App component doesn't take the full width component, so the children take the entire width from the parent but the parent, as I said doesn"t have a width. Add 10%% width to your div tag in your App component

Comment: Added the width, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User agent stylesheet sets the html body { margin: 8 }. To reset you can use the CssBaseline component: https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/

```
App.js:

import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <HomeBody />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I faced the same issue and what I can share to you is that the vw trait will allow you to fully use the Screen. Perhaps from there you can find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

remove body style property in index.css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).